# How to include a function in CPLEX objective function?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to formulate and solve an optimization problem using IBM CPLEX framework using python API.

My objective function is as follows:

[image]

where [image] and [image] are my integer variables. I define the variables as follows in my code:

[image]

function f is as follows:

```
def f(p,n):
   if p==4 and n ==4:
        return 0.8
   elif p==4 and n ==8:
        return 0.9
   elif p==6. and n==4:
        return 0.88
   .
   .
   .
```

My problem:

The problem that I have is about calling function f and using the variable n in that function. Nore specifically, I can not compare this variable to a number suhc as 4 or 8 or I can not use this varibale as the index of a dictionary. The error I get is:
[image]

I tried to implement function f as bellow:

```
def f (p,n):
   my_dictionary = {4:{4:0.8,8:0.9},6:{4:0.88,8:0.92}
   return    my_dictionary[p][n]
```

I get the error of "keyerror  exception" meaning that there is no key as n in my dictionary.

How can I pass the value of my variable to a function and use that value there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use logical constraints:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='test')


n = mdl.integer_var(name='n')
p = mdl.integer_var(name='p')
restimes100=mdl.integer_var(name='restimes100')
res=mdl.continuous_var(name='res')

def f(p,n):
   if p==4 and n ==4:
        return 0.8
   elif p==4 and n ==8:
        return 0.9
   elif p==6. and n==4:
        return 0.88

mdl.add( mdl.logical_and(p==4,n ==4)==(restimes100==80))
mdl.add( mdl.logical_and(p==4,n ==8)==(restimes100==90))
mdl.add( mdl.logical_and(p==6,n ==4)==(restimes100==88))

mdl.add(p==6)
mdl.add(n==4)

mdl.add(res==restimes100*0.01)

mdl.solve()

print("res in cplex = ",res.solution_value)
print("res with f = ",f(6,4))
```

gives

```
res in cplex =  0.88
res with f =  0.88
```

Comment: would you please add one objective also to your example? It would be clear to me how to use it in my context and for my problem. If you want to use my objective goal, you can set the value of lists T, K, and P as T= [0,1], K = [0,1], and P = [4,6].
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your solution :)  the variable n is my decision variable. but here in your example, you have hardcoded the value of n to 4. And also what is the objective command here? Would you please use an objective function similar to mine? Also "p" is not a variable.